# Can any one give me ideas to convert an image (remote url) into base64 in mobile web titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Can any one give me ideas to convert an image (remote url) into base64 in mobile web titanium . I tried

`var data=Ti.Utils.base64encode(remoteUrl);`

which converts remote url into base64 rather than the image exists in that url.
Can any one share your ideas.

Thanks in Advance,
Swathi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you have used (base64encode) accept either a String, a Blob object or a Filesystem.File as a parameter. You're trying to encode a String (your remoteUrl) but this isn't what you actually want!!

You need to get the image, and then you can use it as a parameter for that method. So just request the image and then pass it to the method to get what you want.

```
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
client.onload = function() {
    var base64String = Titanium.Utils.base64encode(this.responseData).getText();
};
client.open("GET", "http://your.remote.url");
client.send();
```

Note that after having used the base64encode method you have a Blob object. If you want to get a String just use the getText method!

You can find more info about the correct use of the base64encode method [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Utils-method-base64encode).